# Drawing inside a QFrame: coordinate system

Tags: qt

I would like to draw inside a Qt QFrame, however the QFrame will have a border. As far as I understand, the paintEvent receives a QPainter which is associated to the whole frameRect, so I will have to offset my paint operations of the border. Is this correct? Is there a way of getting a QPainter already associated to the inner part of the widget, without the (variable in size) border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to consider the  contentsRect contentsRect()-> Returns the area inside the widget's margins.using the return value rect of contensRect() you can restrict to draw anything inside the rect.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to embed a QWidget inside the QFrame, place it in a simple QVBoxLayout layout or QStackedLayout layout with no margins and paint the QWidget instead. You'll probably get better performance if you simply offset your painting, though.